# How to convert this code or list comprehension into iterative version ( in PYTHON )

Tags: python

```
def fizBuz(num):
    """
    Input: An integer (num) that represents the total number in list.
    Output: A list that from 0 to num (inclusive) that 
            if the current number is divisible by 3, the element 
            should say "FIZZ", if divisible by 5, the number should 
            say BUZZ, if divisible by both 3 and 5 should say FIZZBUZZ, 
            if neither the element append the number.
    """
    pass

    #below is a variable with list comprehension
    result = [i if (i == 0) else "FIZZBUZZ" if (i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0)
    else "FIZZ" if (i%3 == 0)else "BUZZ" if (i%5 == 0) else i for i in range(0,num + 1)]

    return result
```

Comment: That IS an iterative version.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Like Tim said, this is an iterative solution.  List comprehensions are iterative by nature.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If the question is just to convert list comp to a regular for loop, I recommend reading the Python docs on list comps to understand how they work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I am sorry guys, i was confused by what iterative means. I was referring to the code and how to convert it into for loop. Thanks a lot for replying and tryna help me.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, list comprehension is in fact the iterative version. I'm assuming you wanted a code written in a `for` loop. If so, there you go -

```
def fizBuz(num):
    sol = []
    for i in range(num+1):
        if not i%3 and not i%5:    print("FIZZBUZZ")
        elif not i%3:    print("FIZZ")
        elif not i%5:    print("BUZZ")
        else:  sol.append(i)
    return sol
```